# proguard don't keep anonymous class

Tags: android, proguard

I got error in runtime:

> Could not find class 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$5',
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.addOnLayoutChangeListenerToDropDownAnchorSDK11

I tried to keep this class by this proguard config:

```
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
                SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { public *; }

-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$* {
    *;
}
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView** {
    *;
}

-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$5 {
    *;
}
```

but without luck. This is not first time proguard don't keep members by config, but this time I can't rewrite code to convert anonymous to inner class.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me (without public):

```
 -keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have the latest proguard version on `<Android SDK>/tools/proguard` and then take a look on `proguard-android.txt`. The latest proguard version provide better configurations for android.

Some definitions that might help you:

```
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

Comment: I am using newest SDK and exactly default config as your. But no one rule match my issue.

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard can't find the class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$5 in your code or libraries. You should check that android/support/v7/widget/SearchView$5.class is present in your support jar. It seems to be present in the latest version that I have here, so maybe your copy got corrupted.

Note that adding -keep options won't help here. ProGuard checks the dependencies between classes right after having read them, before using these options.